# Are all weapon types viable late and post-game?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I started playing Dragon Quest 9 recently, and i did some research on forums and other websites about what people say for weapon types in this game. There are some people who say that swords are the strongest and best weapons in the game followed by axe and spear and that other weapon types aren't even worth using in late and post-game.

Now that got me a bit worried. Even if swords, axes and spears are far better then other types in late and post-game are other weapon types still viable or would i have really hard time with them? From what Iv'e read some swords (falcon) are overpowered and so are some axe and spear skills, but i don't really care about being overpowered, I'd be fine with other weapon types as long as they don't get so weak in late and post-game that it would be very hard to play the game.

I'd appreciate as much information about this as possible as I'd really like to play with other weapon types then swords, spears and axes but not if they're utterly weak late/post game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason swords, spears, and axes are so widely-used in the post-game is because that's when you really need high levels to complete grottos and such; level-grinding pretty much translates to "farming metal slime variants", and each of those three weapon types have abilities on their mastery tree that are basically essential to metal slime farming. (Swords have Metal Slash for extra damage and Falcon Slash for multiple hits, spears have Pressure Point for the rare insta-kill and Thunder Thrust for hit-or-miss critical attacks, and axes have Hatchet Man, basically the axe variation of Thunder Thrust.)

It's difficult to gauge which weapon type is best, however, because each type has various traits that make it stand out from all the others. Giving wands to your magic-users can boost their max MP and allow them to use some nifty crowd-control abilities; claws and spears both have abilities that hit multiple times, some striking random targets each time; whips and boomerangs hit multiple foes with every strike; and hammers and axes give warriors the raw attack power to dish out serious damage, highly useful for piercing enemy defenses. In other words, there's no weapon class that trumps all the others; figure out what kind of team you need for a particular task (surviving a grotto to loot treasures, take down a legacy boss, etc.) and then pick out equipment that'll cater to your team's strengths.

Answer (score 2):

Swords are all round

Wands arent the best but are useful for Sages when the use Magic Burst on High level grotto bosses since they need to restore MP other than that if not equip on sage well , wait for their coup de grace since it restore mp

Fans are useful for multiatcks and matering them to omnivocational and transfering them to vocations such as gladiator make a good charactee and using Fan Dango is even better

Poles , well I dont know

Hammers , bows and spears are very useful since their ablities ( Pressure pointer , Parralx and Needle shot ) can be used for metal slime farming and legacy boss farming for orbs to make legandarh weapons,

Axes the same as above

Answer (score 2):

Swords are made for boss fights, spears are balanced, the best spear can ignore shield' s blocking effect, it is useful for metal hunting, hammers give you two AOE attacks one is earth and the other is dark, bows are versatile weapons with a wide range of effects, boomerang give the ability to hit all does regardless of vocations, wands give you mp boosts, regeneration , zing and a healing ability. Axes are raw power they are versatile too, their skills cost low mp , fisticuffs and staves provide a boost to evasion, fisticuffs have useful skills, staves have counter, whips hit a group of enemies maybe the gringham whip hits all enemies. Fans are mainly support weapons the best fans had a wide range of useful effects on it, hustle dance might help you save mp while healing, knives work around status effects so their skills are useless the weapons they have could be useful poison moth knife might paralyze a enemy, assassin daggers have instant death chance, falcon knife earring let you double hit until you get a falcon blade, they are useless against bosses.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you want the best weapon in the game, it's going to be a sword. Uber Falcon Blade, or, the ultra rare, ultra powerful Hypernova blade. No other weapon will beat these, in a competition for raw power.  However, you have skills specific to weapons that could potentially win you the battle. Personally, I think the Uber Falcon Blafe is best for me, especially when I use Falcon Slash.